# How can I send the user saved in passport from the backend server to the React frontend server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, passport.js, backend

I am using a backend server that handles the logic together with a frontend server in React. What I need is to send the logged user from the backend server to the frontend server. But first I am going to explain how my code flow works in a basic way once the user logs in.

```
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'celnumber',
  passwordField: 'celnumber',
  passReqToCallback: true
  }, async (req, names, celnumber, done) => {
    const user = await userController.findByCelNumber(celnumber);
    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, localStorage.setItem('failureMessage', 'El número ingresado no existe.'));
  }
  localStorage.setItem('successMessage', 'Te has logueado satisfactoriamente.')
  return done(null, user);
}));
```

Once the login has been successful, it is redirected to the frontend server from the `successRedirect`:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local-signin",
   {
     successRedirect: "http://localhost:3001",
     failureRedirect: "/users/login",
     passReqToCallback: true
   }
));
```

**Clarification**: The `successRedirect:" http: // localhost: 3001 "` is only there so that passport don't throw me any errors, but i'm not really using it at all. I am doing the redirection by a window.location.href shown below.

And finally, it comes to my custom hook `useFormHelper`where I redirect the frontend server to render the initial page.

```
if(type === "login") {
   e.preventDefault();
   await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', form).then(async function (response){
      alert("Logueo completado satisfactoriamente.")
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/";
   });
}
```

**My question then is**, how can I send the user logged into passport from the backend server itself to the React frontend server?

I saw in a similar post that I could use my windows.location.href and pass it the user such as: `window.location.href =" http: // localhost: 3001 / "+ user`, but in theory it is not very secure.
It also occurred to me to send the user through the succesRedirect but I don't have a 'req' to send the passport req.user. `successRedirect:" http: // localhost: 3001 "+ req.user,`

I hope I have explained myself correctly, do not hesitate to ask me anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `router.post` add a callback function where you will have req and res as arguments:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local-signin",
   {
     successRedirect: "http://localhost:3001",
     failureRedirect: "/users/login",
     passReqToCallback: true
   }
), (req, res)=>{
        // If you use "Content-Type": "application/json"
        // req.isAuthenticated is true if authentication was success else it is false
        res.json({auth: req.isAuthenticated()});
});
```

in frontend in then function you can have an argument like this:

```
axios.post(Your code).then((res)=>res.data.auth); // res.data will be the object that was sent from backend
```

Comment: Thanks Luka, it worked fine. In the other hand i had to reference in the frontend with `res.config.data` instead of `res.data.auth`, but i have my user object anyways. Thanks again!